# Simplify the division of Normals cumulatives functions

Tags: r, numeric, cdf, simplification

I'm struggling on how I can simplify the quotient of two normal probability functions in `R`. Actually, I'm calculating a conditional skew-Normal density, them I have the division between this two function:

```
pnorm(alpha0+t(alpha2)%*%chol2inv(chol(omega2))%*%t(y2-xi2.1))/pnorm(tau2.1)
```

where `alpha0+t(alpha2)%*%chol2inv(chol(omega2))%*%t(y2-xi2.1)` and `tau2.1` result in real numbers. For example, sometimes I have `pnorm(-50)/pnorm(-40)`, e.g. an inconsistency `0/0`. But these values are not zero, `R` is just approximating. I tried to use the `erf` function, but I got the same problem `(0/0)`.

Any hint on how can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pnorm` has a `log` parameter, which makes it return log(p). Change your equation to exp(log(p1) - log(p2)):

```
exp(pnorm(-50, log = TRUE) - pnorm(-40, log = TRUE))
#[1] 2.95577e-196
```

Comment: works perfectly for me! I didin't know about this parameter.

Comment: You are not the first one with this issue. It is very common in statistics.

Comment: Actually, we need to apply the `exp` separately.

Comment: I don't understand.